# Needed expect in typescript generics

Tags: typescript, redux, reducers

I'd like to type up a function that creates a reducer. I am really close, but it's not working.

```
// Single handler
type HandlerType<T, P> = (state: T, action: { action: string, payload?: any }) => Partial<T>

// Handlers object - key is string and value is a function as above
type HandlersType<T, P> = {
    [key in keyof P]: HandlerType<T, P>
}

const createReducer = <T, P>(
    initialState: T,
    handlers: HandlersType<T, P>,
) => (
    state = initialState,
    action: {
        [a in keyof P]: HandlerType<T, P>
    }
) => {
        const handler = handlers[action.type]

        if (handler) {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...handler(state, action),
            }
        }
    return state
}


// helper generic:
type StatePartial<T, P> = (state: T, { action, payload }: { action: string, payload: P }) => Partial<T>



// ==============================================
// usage:
//

// initial state type
export type StateType = {
    c: string,
    d: string
}

// actions type
export type Actions<T> = {
    'hello': StatePartial<T, string>
}

// actuall creator 
const a = createReducer<StateType, Actions<StateType>>(
    {
        c: 'meh',
        d: 'meh2'
    },
    {
        'hello': (state, payload) => {
            return {
                dateRange: payload
            }
        }
    },
)
```

I'd love some help if that is possible please.

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=64&pc=1#code/PTAEGUEsDsHMBsCmoAWBDaATJAnAUAC4CeADsgBIbaI4AqpiAPLQDSgAKAfKALygAUAZwJoCiAFyhWoNAGMCkAPbRJAbxnylK0MJwxYbEmiLxFaTAH5JGIqAC%20ASl7d2aHArTxmnPHhChKLFxBUEUAIwArRHlQAFpQAGtEW0gQ3X0ZLFAAN08AV2RUmVAAMzzoTWUZELQwxWzEQgYAqmD6MmY2Ll5QVTxQAdAAbSSU6ETkxRKOAF1JQOo6Bk6OHztfWWVhUFkcRFFEACVETDzZGh6Vrn5%20wZhID3hwETFJVluB9CCaQXnWn-aTGkXBYeCcPG4N0GOheyD490ezwOoOhcgUyjUH2hwzQoBgEyIU1mf2%20Sw6wJ80PW4O4fWxg020G2X0WPRZwSGaK0ADpiGQZr56QNINN%20OyaE46ULoXsCHkcOMpdL6dzVcJkVjlYNVdzxTghLC2FzlA4UVr7JrBusZYg5QqYQc8OtfP4UIh4GQcKBYIhoDRILJxE0yBBYa53JBPFduHwDQc3mx1MboIZjKZzPY1Bp0dp0nBUyYzJhJOx7DSOG5Ht5fC6wDx6w3G03my3W22eH4wHlBGgfUGQLW8dAHpH4A6xKA%20Y1EAAPEiKdyT5pIsSAnpKnaSPMGLHFmF6OBOwfJkJTvCz%20eLqegACClSZ3nXWIA5G74KZn5IV4hw1XpNu1mPeQ8k8Mddn2AgF1APBGW2XE%20HAg5jlOc4cEYb9ATYO8c0EdDYUBThOChQYN2hQNQGfABbRAUGfM16T3KiaIAJmfLE7Ho3pLQGV93Q-SQ4zEAt00wctSKFWV5UVbjlUwJCMD7UAjELcwZKpGTrStUEHDwIA)

Comment: I'd specifically encourage you to use [our new official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  It has that same kind of [`createReducer` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer), with the added benefit of using Immer internally to allow simpler immutable updates.  Also, the [`createSlice` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) automatically generates action types and action creators for you, so you don't have to write them by hand.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It won't cut it as bringing in new dependency is a no go. Although I will try to analyze their typings and add it to my lib :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is adding new dependencies an issue?

Comment: That was my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I was going too specific with typings. If I am using generics, it's ok to typehint `any`

```
const createReducer = <T, P extends { [type: string]: any }>(
    initialState: T,
    handlers: P,
) => (
    state = initialState,  
    action: any //  <---- will still be recognized on the next layer
) => {
        const handler = handlers[action.type]

        if (handler) {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...handler(state, action),
            }
        }
        return state
    }


export type State = {
    c: string,
    d: string
}

export type Actions<T> = {
    'hello': (state: T, action: { action: string, payload: string }) => Partial<T>
}

const handlers: Actions<State> = {
    'hello': (state: State, { payload }) => {
        return {
            c: payload
        }
    }
}


const a = createReducer<State, Actions<State>>(
    {
        c: 'meh',
        d: 'meh2'
    },
    handlers,
)
```

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=45&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAlRATArsR8MAvDADwAqANDAAoyIAeaYWEMA3jANpQCeADogBcMaPACWYAOYBdEcjC8YAXwB8ACgBQMHTEnio45ABsAylFTCYVbboAWCrMYIQRNSpoCUxVTC27RCzRiPTADIzMgxA8A5GBDcHlFLx8OWwCdUEhYBxZnQhJcpxcuOISwADo%20QRlNdIzxADM-IvzvdnqM3SQoHHgwNK6h3QrR6EsY4aHRitaCdXG0ajLxcE9JqZVO3WVtnR6%20gcXEet26xn4QeFhqxBhzSxCOgOARMUkpDZgsN6gJaU0ZwuVxuAjuAEF4qtIBRfCRnroAOR2RDGYwgREiBZRERUGArRIcfFQwnvaTUfjIXjo5A-QL-KQqbxEXw0ZDXCKwwF1LLQGBzeCuGCQ8oQUgPNBwwZIlFojFY44iCXRImU6kgWlM1IIroHfrSzavGBqmlYPZbAK7M6aXmwZAhBAoNCYXD4eDiqLUEXQsXK1Qaeo6jJGxEAW0QdkRXwCdLDEYATIjTl8BRAPJ5NEA)